# Upgrade SharePoint 2010 WebTemplate to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, web-template

I had a SharePoint 2010 project that deploys a WebTemplate to the farm. I upgraded the project to make it compatible with SharePoint 2013 and updated the solution in SharePoint farm. Now, when I try to create a new site or site collection based on this template, template is not listed in the available list. Template is only available in the site collection creating page, if I select 2010 compatibility mode.

I updated in the onet.xml file the UIVersion to 15, but nothing changed. Template is still missing.

Should I change anything else to make the previous SharePoint 2010 WebTemplate compatible with SharePoint 2013?

Comment: I tried it myself - changing the UIVersion from 4 to 15 did work. Is it available with get-spwebtemplate in powershell? whats the compatibility level there?

Comment: @MaxMelcher, template is available with Get-SPWebTemplate, but not available in the UI. I changed the UIVersion attribute on the onet.xml without effect. What do you mean by "compatibility level" and how I can check this? Thanks

Comment: did you try the msdn link which shows the upgrade process here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn175700.aspx